# CentOS 7 Asterisk + FreePBX Install:

Tags: centos7, asterisk, freepbx

I attempted to run a ./install -n on my FreePBX install and got:

```
=====
Checking if Asterisk is running and we can talk to it as the 'asterisk' user...Error!
Could not determine Asterisk version (got: No ethernet interface found for seeding global EID. You will have to set it manually.). Please report this.
=====
```

Doing core show version on Asterisk gives me `No ethernet interface found for seeding global EID. You will have to set it manually.` and then the version number on the line under.

I have looked around and unable to find a solution

Comment: Are your netwerk interfaces named eth0, eth1 etc. or are they like nic0, nic1 or the more modern enp2s0 etc.? It could be that the procedure is looking for ethX. If so, do `/sbin/ip link set nic1 name eth1` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In source file freepbx/installlib/installcommand.class.php

Replace line **266** to be like the following:

```
$lastline = exec("runuser" . $answers['user'] . ' -s /bin/bash -c "cd ~/ && asterisk -rx \'core show version\' | grep ^Asterisk 2>&1"', $tmpout, $ret);
```

Instead of:

```
$lastline = exec("runuser" . $answers['user'] . ' -s /bin/bash -c "cd ~/ && asterisk -rx \'core show version\' 2>&1"', $tmpout, $ret);
```